# MySQL: Selecting a row where a column equals the ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my query:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'vreb_property'
AND post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

In this scenario, I need to modify my query to include `WHERE post_parent = ID` ... so the ID that is being selected, I need to use.

`SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'vreb_property' ... and also select records where 'post_parent' = ID`

Because there are records that are of `post_type` "attachment" that I need to grab.

Could I get a few eyes just to clarify the validity of this request? Thanks.

Comment: a known id you are passing in the query?

Comment: Well, it's a little more complicated than that ... I edited my questio above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `OR`?

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE (post_type = 'vreb_property'
       AND post_status = 'publish')
   OR (post_type = 'attachment'
       AND post_parent = ID)
ORDER BY post_modified DESC
```

Using the brackets you can adapt it to your specific needs as that is not completely clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only returns me a few results ... the condition is `post_parent = ID` but what needs to come back is not only the rows that match `post_type = 'vreb_property' AND post_status = 'publish'` but also those that match `post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent = ID`

Comment: @dcolumbus That is just a small change to the conditions, see my edit. The trick is in the parentheses.

Comment: This is unfortunately still only returning 10 results ... so just to clarify, I need both scenarios to come through in the results. `post_type = 'vreb_property' AND post_status = 'publish'` as well as `post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent = ID`

Comment: @dcolumbus That is exactly what this query is selecting. If does not give the desired result, you should post the complete actual code and examples of rows that are not selected.

Comment: It only gives me the `vreb_property` rows ... no additional rows that are `attachments`... which I know are dozens.

Comment: @dcolumbus You should put up some examples.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21476/discussion-between-dcolumbus-and-jeroen)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with jeroen's sql , The trick is in parentheses.